# AngularJS factory only called once

Tags: angularjs

I have a quiz type application with a factory that gets a list of questions from the server:

```
xoryApp.factory('questionService', function($http) {  
  return {
  qdata : function(callback) {
      $http.get('/static/question.json').success(callback);
  }
};
});
```

Then I call this factory in my controller like this:

```
questionService.qdata(function(results) {
    $scope.qdata = results;
});
```

Then I switch back and forth between question and answer partial views as I loop through the questions. The problem is that every time the question view loads, it re-loads the factory json from the server. But I want it to only do that once when I load the app, not every time I load a partial view that uses that controller.

What is the way that you achieve that in angular?

Thanks

Comment: in call questionService.qdata inside a function? Or this code is placed in the controller root?

Comment: its in the root of the controller

Comment: Every times that teh controller is loaded, it will call this function because the root code will be executed. You need to put inside a function and call conditionally. I will create a plunker for you now, 5 minutes =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THis happens because you are calling the factory inside the controller root function.
Everytime that the controller was loaded, it will call the factory again.

I propose this [plunker as solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/AbHSq3t15GFAXpJ9qtFy?p=preview). Maybe it's not the best, but works fine.

In this case I save the list instance on a variable inside the factory, and will loaded just once. If you need to refresh, then you can call a different function to force the refresh to the server-side.

Here a couple of possible solutions:

```
app.factory('questionService', function($http) {  
  var result;
  return {
      qdata : function(callback) {
          return result;
      },
      fecthData : function(callback) {
          result = $http.get('question.json').success(callback);
          return result;
      }
};
});

app.factory('questionService2', function($http) {  
  var result;
  return {
      qdata : function(callback) {
          if (!result) {
              result = $http.get('question2.json').success(callback);  
          }
          return result;
      },
      refreshQdata : function (callback) {
         return $http.get('question2.json').success(callback);  
      }
};
});
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

Cache the results of the server call inside the service method and you are good to go

```
xoryApp.factory('questionService', function($http) {
var questions;
  return {
  qdata : function(callback) {
      if(questions) {
          callback(questions);
      }
      else {
        $http.get('/static/question.json').success(function(data) {
         questions=data;
         callback(questions);
        });
     }

  }

};
});
```